# I simply want to output my Python results into CSV

Tags: python, csv

I simply want to output my Python results into CSV.

The same which we achieve through this on local.

This is a sample result:

```
2022-12-01 , appname, resourcetype , 200 , Amazon Relational Database Service
```

Here is a sample code:

```
def data():       

    for result_by_time in results:

        for group in result_by_time['Groups']:

            amount = group['Metrics']['UnblendedCost']['Amount']
            resource_type = 'Amazon Relational Database Service'

            print(
                result_by_time['TimePeriod']['Start'],
                ',',
                ', '.join(group['Keys'])
                    .replace("example$", "").replace("Name$", ""),
                ',',
                amount,
                ',',
                resource_type,
            )
```

Comment: can you post a fragment of `results` ?

Comment: Decide for a Python version and remove the wrong tag.

Comment: Added the sample result:

2022-12-01 , appname, resourcetype , 200 , Amazon Relational Database Service

Comment: So you want the python code to write to the csv file directly, without having to do the shell `>>` redirect?

Comment: IT is not clear what you want. Maybe have a look at `csv` package.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon for the hint, I will use Shell Script instead.